# CentOS 7: Почему не создаётся больше 3 screen

Tags: сервер, centos7, gnu-screen

Почему у меня не создаётся больше 3 screen в CentOS 7?
Например, я пишу

```
screen -ls
```

Ответ

There are screens on: 
 752.screen1 (Detached) 
743.screen2 (Detached) 
738.screen3 (Detached)

Потом я пишу, например

```
screen ./test.sh
"нажимаю ctrl + a + d"
screen -ls
```

Ответ

There are screens on: 
752.screen1 (Detached) 
743.screen2 (Detached) 
723.screen4 (Detached)

Тоесть, я вкл четвёртый screen, а третий пропал.

Вот уже живой пример на скриншотах
1.У меня 3 screen
[image: скриншот1]

Я пишу

`screen 123`
`"нажимаю ctrl + a + d"`
`screen -ls`

[image: скриншот1]

**Почему? Нормально ли это? Можно ли исправить?**

Comment: Используйте [tmux](https://habr.com/ru/post/327630/), он несколько удобнее screen

Comment: `ps u -C screen` что выдает?

Comment: Так почему может не работать?

Comment: Я написал #ps u -C вот ответ https://pastebin.com/uW9aFgL1

Comment: Что посоветуйте? Как решить?